# Does glutinous rice flour function differently from regular rice flour as a coating?

Tags: flour, starch, sticky-rice

I am going to try making wasabi peas despite a dearth of recipes online. I've read the list of ingredients of several brands, most (including my favorite) contain glutinous rice flour. Others contain rice flour, still others only tapioca and/or corn starch.

My favorite wasabi peas have a very crunchy coating that really looks like it should contain egg whites, but doesn't. [Wasabi Peas](http://www1.search-results.com/picdetails?apn_dbr=&apn_dtid=%5EBND406%5EYY%5EUS&crxv=&itbv=&atb=sysid%3D406%3Aappid%3D390%3Auid%3D670f9408e400d4fe%3Asrc%3Dffb%3Ao%3DAPN10645&p2=%5EAG6%5EBND406%5EYY%5EUS&hdoi=&apn_ptnrs=%5EAG6&o=APN10645&lang=en&gct=ds&tbv=&tpid=&pf=&shad=s_0042&trgb=&apn_sauid=&hpds=&apn_uid=&doi=&q=How+to+Make+Wasabi+Peas%3F&surl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww1.search-results.com%2Fpictures%3Fapn_dtid%3D%255EBND406%255EYY%255EUS%26apn_dbr%3D%26itbv%3D%26crxv%3D%26atb%3Dsysid%253D406%253Aappid%253D390%253Auid%253D670f9408e400d4fe%253Asrc%253Dffb%253Ao%253DAPN10645%26hdoi%3D%26p2%3D%255EAG6%255EBND406%255EYY%255EUS%26apn_ptnrs%3D%255EAG6%26o%3DAPN10645%26lang%3Den%26gct%3Dds%26tbv%3D%26pf%3D%26tpid%3D%26shad%3Ds_0042%26trgb%3D%26hpds%3D%26apn_sauid%3D%26apn_uid%3D%26tpr%3D5%26doi%3D%26q%3DHow%2Bto%2BMake%2BWasabi%2BPeas%253F&purl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.seriouseats.com%2Frecipes%2F2009%2F12%2Fthe-secret-ingredient-wasabi-wasabi-pea-crusted-rare-seared-tuna-recipe.html&iurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.seriouseats.com%2Frecipes%2Fimages%2F20091121WasabiPeas.jpg&iw=500&ih=333&turl=http%3A%2F%2Fmedia4.picsearch.com%2Fis%3Fct67wOtbqZU8sARJmZmU5vUEdnmzkyC0Lsirv940dg0&tw=128&th=86) I've never achieved a coating like that on anything using any starch I'm familiar with, so I'm wondering if glutinous rice flour is key?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried either but I found [this](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100325151201AA8D6TP), which seems helpful:

"there is a big difference between the two..where i come from.(malaysia).we use rice flour to make banana fritters (deep fried in rice flour batter thus giving it a crispy crunchy batter) while glutinous rice flour will give a sticky texture..u cant deep fry the batter but its normally used to make sweet desserts where u boil the cakes in boiling water..when they are cooked they will float and voila... "

I found [this recipe](http://eatdrinkbetter.com/2011/09/16/how-to-make-wasabi-peanuts/) online that uses egg whites for the coating. The recipe says wasabi peanuts but picture is of wasabi peas.

Answer (score 0):

Glutinous rice flour won't give crunch, it is rather chewy, is used for desserts like mochi. I would try tapioca flour or corn starch but definitely not glutinous.